# Count based on two sub groups in Power Bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have Data as in following table, I want to show the % of work order count over the year for each group in stacked area chart but I am struggling to get the correct %. From the below data the % of each Days Delayed group should come as 50%

[image]

Appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create this below **Measure**-

```
group_wsie_percentage = 

VAR total_count = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[days delayed group]),
    ALLEXCEPT(
        your_table_name, 
        your_table_name[year]
    )
)

VAR total_group_count = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[days delayed group]),
    ALLEXCEPT(
        your_table_name, 
        your_table_name[year],
        your_table_name[days delayed group]
    )
)

RETURN total_group_count/total_count
```

Now change the type of measure as **%** and configure your **Stacked** (I used Stacked Bar chart) chart as below-

[image]

Here is the output-

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it has worked now. One more thing, I have legend on this days delayed group but I need to sort legend so 0 days comes before 1-4 days. Can we do that in stacked chart?

Comment: You wants 0 on top of 1-4?

Comment: Yes, now the legend comes as 1-4 then 0

Comment: I think you can post another question by providing the sample data, measure code and current output. Finally explain what is your new issue and how you actually wants to show the chart.

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422431/sort-on-legend-in-stacked-area-chart-power-bi

Comment: I will check soon.