# Sort on legend in Stacked Area Chart Power Bi

Tags: sorting, powerbi, dax, stacked-area-chart

I am using Stack chart on Power BI, I have used Year as x-axis, Group as legend in my graph and % of Work Order as value. I have Sort order of group as well but struggling to sort legends based on Group Sort. Now Legends are not coming in sort order.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow these below steps-

1. Go to the **Model** window and select the table
2. Now select your column **Group**
3. Finally, sort the column using column **Group Short** as shown in the sample image below-

This should order as per your requirement-

[image]

Comment: Can you provide me the report file with sample data?

Comment: How do I provide here?

Comment: Keep the file in One or Google drive and share the link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jKccqcA8etqKoqSzslsN3Zjv0I_IRFeg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please check this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223289/discussion-between-r-r-and-zeeshan-shaikh).